# Evaluation of double integration with polar coordinates

Tags: definite-integrals

> Evaluation of $$\iint_R e^{-(x^2+y^2)} \, dA$$
>
> where $R$ is the region given by inequalities $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ and $0\leq y\leq\sqrt{3}x$

What i try:: drawing Circle and line. We get  a sector which makes an angle of $\pi/3$ with $x$ axis.

Now put $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and $dx\,dy=r\,dr\,d\theta$

So integral is $$\int^{\frac{\pi}{3}}_0 \int^1_0 e^{-r^2}\,dr\,d\theta = \frac{\pi}{6} \bigg(e-1\bigg)$$

Can anyone please tell me is my solution is right? If not then tell me how do I solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Yep... looks fine to me.

Comment: You need $\displaystyle \int^{\frac{\pi}{3}}_0 \int^1_0 e^{-r^2} r\,dr\,d\theta$ rather than $\displaystyle \int^{\frac{\pi}{3}}_0 \int^1_0 e^{-r^2}\,dr\,d\theta. \qquad$

Comment: But the value you get at the end is correct.

Comment: Isn't it rather $\int^{\frac{\pi}{3}}_{0}\int^{1}_{0}re^{-r^2}drd\theta=\frac{\pi}{6}\bigg(1-e^{-1}\bigg)?$

Comment: I edited the question to change $\displaystyle \int\int_R e^{-(x^2+y^2)} \, dA$ to $\displaystyle \iint_R e^{-(x^2+y^2)} \, dA,$ coding it with \iint (with two consecutive "i"s). You can also write $\displaystyle \iint\limits_R e^{-(x^2+y^2)} \, dA$ (with the subscript $R$ formatted differently). $ \qquad$

Comment: Thanks so much Michael Hardy.